# Button "Back" in iOS Simulator i covered with blue rectangle

Tags: ios, swift

When I start iOS Simulator and press first row in viewcontroller it opens another same viewcontroller but at top its blue rectangle which is covering button "Back". What am I missing?

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

class gaga: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return Model.sharedInstace.categoryArray.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell

    let category = Model.sharedInstace.categoryArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.categoryName1.text = category.name
    cell.numberOfSubjects1.text = category.id

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: we can't tell unless we see some code

Comment: how can you expect us to know what the problem is without seeing your code?

Comment: where is the didSelectItem method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was caused by a background image. Try to remove all backgrounds and check, if the issue is gone.

[image]

Comment: yes, that was problem. Had some old images at all three... Tnx @Stefan

Comment: Good to hear, that your issue is solved. Please accept the answer to avoid that other users invest time for answering again ;-)